# Point of division of line segments one is 3/4 as the other

Tags: geometry

The segment joining A(2,-4) and B(9,3) is divided into segments one which is three fourths as long as the other. Find the point of division nearer to B(9,3).

I'll call the point of division as C(x,y).

If i understood the question correctly, AB is divided into 7 segments where there are 2 possible answers:

1. 3 divisions from A to C and 4 divisions from C to B.
2. 4 divisions from A to C and 3 divisions from C to B.

Is this correct?

Comment: It looks good to me. Then,is your choice $1$ or $2$ ?

Comment: Since the question is not clear, I would probably write 2 solutions thanks! ill try to solve it now

Comment: The question is clear since you are asked for the point nearer to $B$

Comment: oh yes, after drawing the figure i completely understood the question. The correct way to go is number 2 since it is nearer to B

Comment: You got it ! Cheers :)